# Job scheduler can't cancel jobs for system uid

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I'm getting the following exception in the logcat when trying to cancel all jobs in my application

```
06-26 11:27:54.866 E/JobSchedulerService( 1246): Can't cancel all jobs for system uid
06-26 11:27:54.866 E/JobSchedulerService( 1246): android.util.Log$TerribleFailure: Can't cancel all jobs for system uid
06-26 11:27:54.866 E/JobSchedulerService( 1246):    at android.util.Log.wtf(Log.java:299)
06-26 11:27:54.866 E/JobSchedulerService( 1246):    at android.util.Slog.wtfStack(Slog.java:98)
06-26 11:27:54.866 E/JobSchedulerService( 1246):    at com.android.server.job.JobSchedulerService.cancelJobsForUid(JobSchedulerService.java:788)
06-26 11:27:54.866 E/JobSchedulerService( 1246):    at com.android.server.job.JobSchedulerService$JobSchedulerStub.cancelAll(JobSchedulerService.java:2033)
06-26 11:27:54.866 E/JobSchedulerService( 1246):    at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub.onTransact(IJobScheduler.java:119)
06-26 11:27:54.866 E/JobSchedulerService( 1246):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
```

Did anyone also encounter with this error? I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

The code for cancelling the jobs is simple, and is following:

```
public static void cancelAllJobs(@NonNull Context context) {
    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    if (jobScheduler != null) {
        jobScheduler.cancelAll();
        Timber.d("All jobs are canceled.");
    } else {
        Timber.w("Job scheduler is not available.");
    }
}
```

**Please note**, my app is declared as system in the manifest with

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```

Comment: Hi Ana, Can you please post the code snippet for cancel job?

Comment: HI Dhaval, I've edited my question and updated it with the code snippet.

Comment: Hi Ana, I have not much knowledge with System Uid, But maybe this link help you https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/c3b1442d520cec596147e45757f433778db23614%5E2..c3b1442d520cec596147e45757f433778db23614/

Comment: HI Dhaval, thanks for the link, I will check it and come back later if I manage to find a conclusion/solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run: `adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler`, you can see all the jobs scheduled under the system uid (#1000).

A job scheduled under an app with a shared uid must ensure that their job id is unique among all the packages using that shared uid. From docs: [*"ID must be unique across all clients of the same uid (not just the same package)."*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder#JobInfo.Builder(int,%20android.content.ComponentName)) The cancelAll() API will cancel all jobs under the calling uid and not just the jobs from the calling package. I would guess that Android restricts a package with the system uid from cancelling all system uid jobs to ensure jobs aren't cancelled unintentionally.

Do you really want to cancel all the jobs from all apps/packages under the system uid?

I have a couple apps using jobscheduler with the system uid and use the following code to cancel a specific job.

```
public static void cancelJob(Context mContext, int jobID) {
    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler)
            mContext.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

    for (JobInfo jobInfo : scheduler.getAllPendingJobs()) {
        if (jobInfo.getId() == jobID) {
            scheduler.cancel(jobID);
            Log.i(TAG,"Cancelled Job with ID:" + jobID);
        }
    }
}
```

Another good post I just ran across:
https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/06/07/jobscheduler-job-ids-libraries.html

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer Steve. I was thinking of sending `ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED` intent to trigger cancel of jobs in my package, but I guess ensuring unique IDs and cancelling jobs with these IDs as you suggested in your answer is more elegant solution.